# Issue with negative margin value in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, margin

I have an issue with a negative margin in Firefox. My negative margin works in Chrome but doesn't in Firefox.

```
.search-bar {
    height: 108px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: I found it works better on FF with positition:absolute

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The solution simply :

```
.search-bar {
    height: 98px;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
```

I Replaced `margin-top` with `top` with the same value, and I decreased `height` with old `margin-top` value, and worked like a charm.

Comment: But then again if you don't know the height this is probably not the correct way to do it

Comment: @tgdn try to ignore height. in my case here i was need to take care about height, if you don't have height then you don't have to do anything with it, but you maybe need do some wrapping in some cases.

Comment: if it still doesn't works for you. Try giving the current div `display:inline-block;` property, then it works in *Firefox* or you can use `float:left` as well. and if `display: inline-block;` or `float:left` breaks your width issue, give it another `width: 100%;`.

Answer (score 6):

For everyone still having the same problem, just add `float:left` to the DOM element with the negative margin. Thanks to [@Deepak Yadav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032598/deepak-yadav) for the solution.

Comment: actually, a float is not just option property, it could break the layout!

Comment: Yup, but in my case it works perfectly and the solution above doesn't. I'm just giving another option for people that might stumble on this problem. 

Comment: Using display: inline-block should also work and may be more compatible with your layout than float:left

Comment: this answer should be marked correct, float: left and width: 100% worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

I did this and this works so perfect.

```
.your__class{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:-100px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use **top** property instead of **margin-top** and assign **position relative**

My Example:

```
div span {
    display: inline-block;
    top: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 3px;
    line-height: 40px;
    position: relative;
```

}